# Ubuntu 20.04 no desktop folders

Tags: unity, 20.04, directory

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 and changing my desktop to Unity on my laptop, the machine's desktop does not show any files or folders, nor does it respond to any attempt to place a file on it or to a right-click.
The desktop is fine if I log in to the gnome option.
The settings on the gnome extensions app are correct but obviously do not carry over to the Unity desktop environment. The extensions app is also not available in Unity.
I have an identical installation on my desktop computer and there everything was fine until a moment ago when I discovered the same problem here.
Display manager is lightdm.
I have also tried Nemo file manager, same result.
Then I edited the Nautilus .config file thus:
https://askubuntu.com/.../desktop-folder-and-files...
Still no luck.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: That's it, cannot even change appearance via right-click but can do via settings menu.